# Not able to create Docker Network

Tags: windows, docker, docker-network

I running docker on windows linux subsystem, docker is running fine when i tried to create new docker network it gives me an error below:

docker network create ariflow

```
*Error response from daemon: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-89eb32911990 -j MASQUERADE: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1))*
```

**ifconfig**

```
> br-89eb32911990: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::893a:d072:c4bd:2499  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:ca  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> br-9a64da919c7b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::bcec:7d41:4fe:c254  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:c3  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> br-ad29a14ced4b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::c8a0:1412:e2e1:4e64  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:bf  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::b5c0:7e07:9857:2a03  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:b4  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.144  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::1980:e807:ae6c:7a07  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:67  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.116  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::58ed:b66c:2593:598b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:66  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.201  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::9837:563e:eb37:9365  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:64  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.127  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::296d:af27:93b0:5f79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:65  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0xfe<compat,link,site,host>
>         loop  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I running docker on windows linux subsystem, docker is running fine when i tried to create new docker network it gives me an error below:

docker network create ariflow

```
*Error response from daemon: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 ! -o br-89eb32911990 -j MASQUERADE: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1))*
```

**ifconfig**

```
> br-89eb32911990: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::893a:d072:c4bd:2499  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:ca  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> br-9a64da919c7b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::bcec:7d41:4fe:c254  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:c3  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> br-ad29a14ced4b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::c8a0:1412:e2e1:4e64  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:bf  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
>         inet6 fe80::b5c0:7e07:9857:2a03  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 02:50:f2:bc:23:b4  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.144  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::1980:e807:ae6c:7a07  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:67  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.116  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::58ed:b66c:2593:598b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:66  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.201  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::9837:563e:eb37:9365  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:64  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.1.127  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
>         inet6 fe80::296d:af27:93b0:5f79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
>         ether 20:04:0f:ec:73:65  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0xfe<compat,link,site,host>
>         loop  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```